# Validar campos não obrigatórios usando Validation do Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-validation, validator, laravel-5.8

Gostaria de validar um campo e que esse campo não fosse obrigatório.

Sei que para ele ser o obrigatório eu devo usar `required` porém não usei, já que eu queria apenas validar um email caso ele fosse adicionado pelo usuário, então utilizei a validação `'email'`.

Mas ocorre que mesmo eu **não usando** o `required` ele por default obriga o usuário a colocar um valor no campo assim deixando o campo obrigatório. Para ficar mais simples vou colocar um código abaixo:

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests\Dashboard;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;


class FormEditarUsuario extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        // dd('ok');

        return [
            'email' => 'email'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {

        return [
            'email.email' => 'Campo email inválido'

        ];

    }

}
```

Resumindo queria validar, mas caso o usuário não coloque nenhum valor no campo ele não retorne um erro de validação!

OBS.: Já tentei usar `min:0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só adicionar o `nullable` na frente:

```
public function rules()
{
    // dd('ok');

    return [
        'email' => 'nullable|email'
    ];
}
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-nullable

Comment: obg cara pior q euli a documentação, mas como eu estava programando de madrugada e eu ja não estava lendo coisa com coisa acho q passou batido, mas obrigado ai ajudou muito abraço irmão!